# Manual estimation of a GARCH(1,1) parameters using MLE vs rugarch package in R

Tags: r, estimation, garch, volatility-forecasting

I want to estimate parameters of a GARCH(1,1) model using rugarch package in R and manually(using maximum likelihood).

Firstly, I import and transfrom the data as below(Amazon return data)

```
library(quantmod)
    amazon<-getSymbols("^DJI",src="yahoo", from="2012-01-01",to="2019-01-01", auto.assign = F)
    amazonlog<-as.data.frame(log10(amazon[,6]))

    N=length(amazonlog[,1])

    amazon_ret<-100*(amazonlog[2:N,]-amazonlog[1:N-1,])
```

Then, I estimate the parameters of GARCH(1,1) using rugarch package in R:

```
library(rugarch)

modelx<-ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)), 
             mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), include.mean = TRUE), 
             distribution.model = "norm",fixed.pars = list(mu=0))

setstart(modelx) <- list(omega=0.2, alpha1 = 0.8, beta1 = 0.2)



fitx = ugarchfit(data =amazon_ret , spec = modelx, method="BFGS")
```

Here, I fixed the starting values as omega=0.2, alpha1 = 0.8, beta1 = 0.2 and mu=0.

The estimated values of coefficients are as below:

```
> coef(fitx)
         mu       omega      alpha1       beta1 
0.000000000 0.008004286 0.172347059 0.763848177
```

After, I am trying to estimate the same coefficients using maximum likelihood method manually using optim function:

```
garch_loglik<-function(para,x,mu){
  # Parameters
  omega0=para[1]
  alpha=para[2]
  beta=para[3]
  # Volatility and loglik initialisation
  loglik=0
  h=var(x)
  # Start of the loop
  vol=c()
  for (i in 2:length(x)){
    h=omega0+alpha*(x[i-1]-mu)^2+beta*h
    loglik=loglik+dnorm(x[i],mu,sqrt(h),log=TRUE)
  }
  print(para)
  return(-loglik)
}

para=c(0.2,0.8,0.2)

mlef<-optim(para, garch_loglik, gr = NULL,method = c("BFGS"),amazon_ret,0)
```

So, I wanted to fix starting values of the parameters as same as ugarhfit to equilize the conditions.

And the estimated values of the coefficients are as below:

```
> mlef$par
[1] 0.008285513 0.174301164 0.759474041
```

So, I estimated coeffifients with rugarch package and manually(using mle method).

The results are close to each other.However, there are some differences between two estimates. I was hoping to get as same as results.

Why are the estimates are diferent from each other?

I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @oercim, hope you are doing well, did you find the reason of the difference between the estimates?

Comment: Hi: This isn't an answer but a lot of times the difference can be due to the tolerance used to decide when to stop. ( i.e: when is numerical gradient close enough to zero ). You'd have to look inside the BFGS code to see what the tolerance is. Also, the algorithm itself matters. Rugarch might not use BFGS which could also cause differences.

Comment: I think the problem might be the mu in this case.